# How to reduce $f(k, n)$ to $\operatorname{fibonacci}(n)$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Let's define $f(k, n)$

$f(0, n) = f(0, n - 1) + f(1, n - 1)$

$f(1, n) = f(0, n - 1)$

$f(k, 1) = 1$, for every $k$.

$k$, $n$ $\subset \mathbb N$, for $0 \le k \le 1, n \ge 1$.

I noted that $f(k, n) =\operatorname{fibonacci}(n)$, for every $k$ and $n$, as long as we define $\operatorname{fibonacci}(1) = 2$, $\operatorname{fibonacci}(2) = 3$.

$$\operatorname{fibonacci}(n) = \operatorname{fibonacci}(n - 1) + \operatorname{fibonacci}(n - 2)\quad,\quad \operatorname{for} n \gt 2$$

How can I prove that?

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t specify initial conditions, so I set $f(0,1)=a$ and $f(1,1)=b$. Here’s a table of the first few values:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
f(0,n):&a&a+b&2a+b&3a+2b&5a+3b&8a+5b\\
f(1,n):&b&a&a+b&2a+b&3a+2b&5a+3b
\end{array}$$

At this point it’s easy to conjecture that $f(0,n)=F_na+F_{n-1}b$, where the $F_n$ are the usual Fibonacci numbers with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$. This is easily proved by induction. To get the induction off the ground, we observe that

$$f(0,1)=a=F_1a+F_0b$$

and

$$f(0,2)=a+b=F_2a+F_1b\;.$$

If $m\ge 3$, and the conjecture holds for $1\le n<m$, then

$$\begin{align*}
f(0,m)&=f(0,m-1)+f(1,m-1)\\
&=f(0,m-1)+f(0,m-2)\\
&=(F_{m-1}a+F_{m-2}b)+(F_{m-2}a+F_{m-3}b)\\
&=F_ma+F_{m-1}b\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Of course we always have $f(1,n)=f(0,n-1)=F_{n-1}a+F_{n-2}b$.

If $a=b=1$, then $f(0,n)=F_n+F_{n-1}=F_{n+1}$, which is what you observed; in this case $f(1,n)=F_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your intuitive and easy to follow answer, I appreciate that.
I'm sorry for not specifying the initial conditions, I edited the question and corrected it.

Comment: @M.M: You’re welcome.